# How to make an element auto-expand to fill space without taking over?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, width, textblock

I am creating a custom calendar in XAML and WPF. The calendar is made up of seven `<Grid>` columns that can auto expand (e.g. `width="1*"`) with the window.

Here's what's happening right now:

[image]

A very wide element "takes over" the columns and makes the others smaller, which is not what I want.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

In this example, the columns auto-expand to fill available width (window size) but an element can't make one column larger. The only way I know to achieve this is by setting the width property (*but then it wouldn't auto-expand*).

Here's sample code. It would produce output like the first image:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello world this is a sample very long text!" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello world !" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

How can I achieve this desired output?

**Edit:** I was using a `ScrollViewer` around my grid (to vertically scroll in case there were many assignments). The property `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` actually caused this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure its the solution for your problem, but you can try to wrap the text if overflows, like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Some long text" TextWrapping="Wrap">
```

Let me know if this helps, if not i can look more into it!

Comment: I had tried this without success but didn't realize my actual issue was with a `ScrollViewer` my `Grid` was wrapped in. You are correct though!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing that behavior. When I try your code snippet, the text doesn't "take over" the other columns. It gets clipped (see below)

[Sample without TextWrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V557x.png)

Seems like you might want to set the TextWrapping attribute of TextBlock to "Wrap".

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello world this is a sample very long text!" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

[Sample with TextWrapping="Wrap"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOQTQ.png)